# Xamarin Forms - Keep portrait width within landscape on tablet devices

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms is there a way to keep the portrait aspect of a view when changed to landscape on a tablet?

I can easily work out what device type I have using `Device.Idiom`, if it's a phone it's already locked to portrait so no problem there.

If it's a tablet, rather than fill the width I want to keep the portrait width but within landscape.

Hope that makes sense.

Update:

I think I can set this within

```
override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
```

I'm just not sure exactly how to set the height / width of the page from here, any ideas?

Comment: Hope it helps: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation/#Controlling_Orientation

Comment: What if you set the orientation of a whole page to fix it like portrait/landscape? Does it works for you?